# React functional component is re-rendering infinite times

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have below functional component.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Link, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';

import { loginUserAction } from './redux/actions/authenticationActions';
import { setCookie } from '../../utils/cookies';

const LoginComponent = () => {
  const [notification, setNotification] = useState('');
  const { loading, error, data } = useSelector(state => state.login || {});

  console.log(data) // returns undefined
  console.log(loading) // false
  console.log(error) // false

  useEffect(() => {
    if (data !== undefined && data.hasOwnProperty('message')) {
      setNotification(data.message);
      setCookie('token', data.token, 1);
      setCookie('id', data.id, 1);
    }
  }, [data]);

  return (
    <div>
      <h3>Login Page</h3>
    </div>
  );
};

export default LoginComponent;
```

As you can see I am passing data as a dependency to useEffect hook. This make useEffect into infinite loop. How can I fix this?

**UPDATE**

The problem is that when remove the useEffect hook completely, the component still re-renders infinite times. Any idea what is happening?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Link, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';

import { loginUserAction } from './redux/actions/authenticationActions';
import { setCookie } from '../../utils/cookies';

const LoginComponent = () => {
  console.log('Rendering') // Renders infinite times.

  return (
    <div>
      <h3>Login Page</h3>
    </div>
  );
};

export default LoginComponent;
```

I get this error.

```
×
Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.
```

Comment: What is datatype of data? Is it array?

Comment: @SaralKarki it is an object in this case but will be array in other cases.

Comment: If you use array in useeffect dependency , it will run infinite loops. Can you try like this? JSON.stringify(data) as useeffect dependency

Comment: Try like how? Can you tell me?

Comment: Does `setCookie` change `data` ?

Comment: Edited my comment

Comment: @nico263nico no it does not.

Comment: @SaralKarki it does not solve the problem.

Comment: Have you tried making the dependency more explicit? `[data?.message, data?.token, date?.id]`

Comment: @FelixKling I just tried it and still infinite loop.

Comment: Unless `data` has a reference to _new_ object after each render, there's no reason for `useEffect` to execute multiple times.

Comment: @Yousaf how can I find if data has a reference to new object?

Comment: Create a variable outside the component; inside the component, check if the newly created variable is undefined or not; if it is, then assign `data` to this variable. If the value of the variable is not undefined, then compare it with the `data`: `myVar === data`. If this condition is false, then this means that `data` points to a new object while `myVar` points to the object which was pointed to by `data` in the previous render.

Comment: @Yousaf `myVar === data` returns false. Which means data does not point to new object.

Comment: Is there any way you can create a reproducible `codesandbox`? Unless `data` isn't changed elsewhere, this `useEffect` shouldn't render infinite times

Comment: @SinanYaman for that I also have to design the backend because currently this makes a request to local api to receive data from.

Comment: try finding if the data is being updated here/somewhere else, that should fix your issue; useEffect should not run in infinite loop unless the data is being modified constantly.

Comment: Yeah, it is hard then :/ I would remove `setNotifications` and try again, then remove `setCookies` and try again, then put a debugger in the reducer to see when it changes data. Good luck

Comment: @SinanYaman I updated my question could you please take a look at it?

Comment: _"`myVar === data` returns false. Which means data does not point to new object."_ no, it means `data` points to a new object.

Comment: _"The problem is that when remove the useEffect hook completely, the component still re-renders infinite times"_ - in that case, look at the parent component. Problem is likely in any of the parent or ancestor components of the `LoginComponent`. Re-rendering of parent component, by default, re-renders all its child components.

Comment: Can you also include where you render `<LoginComponent />`

Comment: I suspect,  The issue could be in the **setCookie**

Comment: Basically the problem was in JSX. I put a condition in JSX to show errors if there are any that condition was placed in wrong way. I fixed it already.